# Instrumenting JS api call from a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am writing a FF extension that will modify the behavior of an existing webpage.  A page from the site makes a call (via Javascript) back to a server (via a public api) that I would like to augment.

Does anyone know how I might do something like this?  Not exactly sure where to start.

Thank you very much,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to first figure out how the web page you're trying to extend does the call you want to augment. Firebug and inspecting the source will be helpful here.

Then use [GreaseMonkey](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual) or a reimplement parts of it to make the necessary changes to the page.